# how can telephony manager conditionally listen to multiple PhoneStateListener's events?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, phone-state-listener

I'm having a Telephony Manager listening to CALL_STATE.

Now I want to additionally listen to DATA_CONNECTION_STATE and SERVICE_STATE using the same telephony manager but under different conditions (plz refer to the following code snippet)

How can I do it?

My current code seems not to work properly

```
telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            // do something
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            break;
        }
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
    }

    public void onServiceStateChanged(ServiceState serviceState) {
        switch (serviceState.getState()) {
        case ServiceState.STATE_EMERGENCY_ONLY:
        case ServiceState.STATE_OUT_OF_SERVICE:
            // do something
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        super.onServiceStateChanged(serviceState);
    }

    public void onDataConnectionStateChanged(int state) {
        switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.DATA_DISCONNECTED:
            // do something
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        super.onDataConnectionStateChanged(state);
    }
};

btnRun.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (some conditions) {
            telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener,
                    PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        }
        if (some conditions) {    // additionally listen to more states
            telephonyManager
                    .listen(phoneStateListener,
                            PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_DATA_CONNECTION_STATE);
        }
        if (some conditions) {    // additionally listen to more states
            telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener,
                    PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SERVICE_STATE);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any suggestion please?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

You can OR the flags together when registering via listen()

### Documentation

[here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#listen(android.telephony.PhoneStateListener,%20int))

Comment: Hi. Thanh you! But here I want to listen to more states additionally since I'm having 3 different conditions for 3 states. If I uses OR flag, I will have several cases, and the code will look complicated.

Comment: You're asking.. how do you listen to multiple states. The answer is you OR them and it doesn't complicate them, its just adding them together. There is no other way.